# Difference between HFP 1.6 and HFP 1.5?

Tags: bluetooth, hfp

Can someone please help in getting the difference between HFP 1.6 and HFP 1.5 ?
Any link or available document?

Comment: Find documentation in Google, Ask question in Stack Overflow. Don't mix up.

Comment: I didn't find any info available to this. please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the Wikipedia page on Bluetooth profiles:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile

Specifically under the HSP section:

Version 1.6 adds optional support for wide band speech with the mSBC codec, a 16 kHz monaural configuration of the SBC codec mandated by the A2DP profile.